# How to remove unwanted data padding from custom sections on XC16

Tags: c, embedded, microchip, pic24, xc16

I am currently trying to dev a firmware for a PIC24F using the whole microchip stack (xc16, mcc, mplab X IDE, etc ...) (not necessarily relevant but i work on a debian 22)

Doesn't really matter why but i want to place some data on a specific section that i will place at specific location on my firmware.

Let's imagine i have a struct `my_struct` defined in `file.h` as follow :

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)   // using pragma pack to pack the struct and avoid padding
typedef struct {
    uint16_t magic;
    uint32_t length;
    uint32_t crc;
    uint16_t word_1;
    uint16_t word_2;
    uint8_t byte_1;
    uint8_t byte_2;
    uint8_t byte_3;
    uint8_t array[15];
}  my_struct;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

then in my `file.c` :

```
const my_struct  __attribute__((section("my_section"))) instance = {
    .magic            = 0xbaba,
    .crc              = 0xbabababa,
    .length           = 0xbabababa,
    .byte_1           = 0xba,
    .byte_2           = 0xba,
    .byte_3           = 0xba,
    .word_1           = 0xbaba,
    .word_2           = 0xbaba,
    .array            = {0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba }
};
```

When I create the object file `file.o`,
I expect having a section `my_section` of size 32 and filled with 0xBA. So I try to inspect the produced `file.o` using objdump to ensure that the data are the one that I want

```bash
$ size -A file.o
section           size   addr
[...]
my_section              64      0
```

```bash
$ objdump -s -j my_section file.o

Contents of section my_section:
 0000 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0010 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0020 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0030 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
```

But it seems like XC16 added a `00` padding for each data byte and that it doubled the size of the section.

I know that padding is to keep data aligned for optimization purpose, but for this specific case, I really need those data to be packed and the size needs to be 32.

The issue is not only in `file.o`, even if I go until the end of the compilation process, I manage to have the section located where i want (thanks to an updated linker script) but it still contains the unwanted padding. So i'm pretty sure the issue is not about linker, but about the compilation process itself

I tried a loooot of things, really.

I tried to pack the structure using :
`#pragma pack(1)` (with or without push/pop)
I also tried to use `__packed`
or `__atribute__((packed(1)))`

I tried to add the `aligned(1)` keyword, or the `volatile` specifier
I even tried to use some `uint32_t arr[8]`, `uint16_t arr[16]` and  `uint8_t arr[32]` instead of a struct.
I tried a lot of mplab project configuration (i can't remember which ones, probably all of them)
I tried all those options separately and together ...

But nothing changes the output. I checked documentation or anything i could, but i can't make it work.
Is this even possible under xc16 or should i give up?

### === EDIT ===

Thanks to @pmacfarlane and @thebusybee, I dug a little further and here is what i found:

I declared two identical structs

- one (`s1`) with the `__attribute__((used, section("my_section"))`,
- the other (`s2`) with no attribute

when i compile and inspect `file.o`

I got the same output as before for the `my_section` output, coming from `s1`.
And some data has been added to the .const section, coming from `s2`:

```bash
$ objdump -s -j .const file.o

Contents of section .const:
 0000 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0010 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0020 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0030 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
```

So nothing new here, but if I inspect the final elf, there is a difference :

```bash
$ objdump -s -j .const firmware.elf

Contents of section .const:
 82cc baba0000 baba0000 baba0000 baba0000  ................
 82dc baba0000 baba0000 baba0000 baba0000  ................
 82ec baba0000 baba0000 baba0000 baba0000  ................
 82fc baba0000 baba0000 baba0000 baba0000  ................
```

```bash
$ objdump -s -j my_section firmware.elf

Contents of section my_section:
 0000 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0010 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0020 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
 0030 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00 ba00ba00  ................
```

Please note that i am using the default linker script for this example.

I tried to add some code in it , even to modify it entirely but, as nothing worked as expected, I went back to the default one.
For minimal reproducible purpose, i even ended up removing everything about section management, and the result stays the same. So i think the behaviors is coming from the xc16 linker default behavior and not from the linker script.
I would gladly add the linker script to the question but it is 3k lines long.
So, it looks like the linking process is packing ba00ba00 into baba0000 for built-in section such as `.const` but not for my custom section.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I assumed that this would bring more information. Any hints ?

Comment: That's.... really weird. If you just let it be in the `.data` (or `.rodata`) section do you see the same?

Comment: If you tag this as `C` you'll probably have a vastly bigger audience. Maybe someone will have an idea. The tags you've used are accurate, but probably nobody is watching many of them.

Comment: Assumed that your tool chain uses a linker script, please [edit] your question and add it. -- How is a "normal" constant like `static const uint32_t C = 0x12345678;` stored in `.rodata`? Is it possible that your target reads every other byte from such memory?

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thanks for your answers, you're right, I will add the `C` tag.  
I tried your idea and got the same output, from .data or from .const (with the const specfier).  
So the problem does not come from the custom section

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for your answer

I could add the linker script, but i inspect the `file.o` which is produced before any linking process. I can be wrong, but I think the linker script is not relevant here.

For the test you wanted me to do with the normal variable, i got 
`Contents of section .const: 0000 78005600 34001200`.  => with const specifier.  
`Contents of section .ndata: 0000 78005600 34001200`.  => without const specifier.  


So, same problem.

Comment: PICs are known to have word sizes other than 8 or 16 bits. You might want to check this.

Comment: How about something like this: `__pack_upper_byte char message[] = "Hello World!\n";` ? (From section 10.10.1 of this [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20XC16%20C%20Compiler%20Users%20Guide%20DS50002071.pdf))

Comment: if added the ` __pack_upper_byte` in front of my structure declaration, i now got :
`bababa00 bababa00 bababa00 bababa00` 

That's way better now ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to mark this thread as resolved, I will post this answer, but the credit is not for me.

As pointed out by @thebusybee, the issue was coming from the fact that the pic I was using, uses 24bits words.

And as @pmacfarlane said, the solution was in this [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20XC16%20C%20Compiler%20Users%20Guide%20DS50002071.pdf).

> For 16-bit devices, a 24-bit word is used in Flash memory. The architecture supports the
> mapping of areas of Flash into the data space, but this mapping is only 16 bits wide to
> fit in with data space dimensions, unless the __pack_upper_byte qualifier is used

So by declaring my struct as follows :

```
__pack_upper_byte const my_struct __attribute__((section("my_section"))) instance = {
    .magic            = 0xbaba,
    .crc              = 0xbabababa,
    .length           = 0xbabababa,
    .byte_1           = 0xba,
    .byte_2           = 0xba,
    .byte_3           = 0xba,
    .word_1           = 0xbaba,
    .word_2           = 0xbaba,
    .array            = {0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba, 0xba }
};
```

I ended up with

```bash
objdump -s -j my_section binary.elf

binary.elf:     file format elf32-little

Contents of section my_section :
 0000 bababa00 bababa00 bababa00 bababa00  ................
 0010 bababa00 bababa00 bababa00 bababa00  ................
 0020 bababa00 bababa00 baba0000
```

Which is way better than before, thank you very much for your help !